# iterating through objects array Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, web, frontend

I'm returning array of objects from my backend that looks like this:

```
 "courses": 
[
    {
        "_id": "5a0eb3d7f6b50c2589c34e57",
        "name": "Js",
        "started": 1990,
        "author": "Author",
        "description": "Building static pages is great, but sometimes we need to feed dynamic content into our templates. Because Perk is built on top of Express, it supports all the templating engines and ships with ejs. ",
        "lessons": 1,
        "__v": 0,
        "subscribers": [],
        "tasks": [
            "fwefwfwrfrewgerg"
        ],
        "lectures": [
            "qefefwefweqd"
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "5a2e789db3f2bc195cbfafe2",
        "name": "erg",
        "started": 1990,
        "author": "ergeg",
        "description": "ergreg",
        "lessons": 1,
        "image": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dk34qvajk/image/upload/v1512994973/yjq40xtrarwi3sgrbwgn.jpg",
        "__v": 0,
        "subscribers": [],
        "tasks": [
            "ergerg"
        ],
        "lectures": [
            "ergerg"
        ]
    }
]
```

than I'm trying to iterate through by using

```
ng-repeat="course in courses"
```

and display course name by {{course.name}} , author etc in html file but get error [image: photo]

courses.component.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getCourses().subscribe(data=>{
      this.courses = data.courses;
      console.log(this.courses)
    },
    err=>{
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    });
  }
```

Comment: ng-repeat should be *ngFor="let course of courses". Ng-repeat does not exist in Angular 2

Comment: Seeing your actual HTML would help, but that said, @DavidAnthonyAcosta is correct, and it is probably the correct answer.

Comment: okay  that solved my problem. thank you a lot